# Параллельные транзакции. Best practices

Tags: база-данных, многопоточность, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. В своём проекте использую EntityFramework.
Есть сервер, к которому подключаются клиенты. 
- Каждое подключение в отдельном потоке.
- В каждом подключении берутся данные из базы, изменяются и записываются обратно (за одну транзакцию)

Столкнулся с тем, что два пользователя могут изменять одни данные и получится "состояние гонки".
(т.е. Они берут `А=1` и делают `А++`, а в итоге записывается `А=1` вместо `А=2` (два раза инкремент))

Единственным решением нашел использовать только одно возможное подключение, но в этом случае `пользователь2` будет ждать `пользователя1`

Какой есть выход из этой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать `IsolationLevel.Serializable` у транзакции, то применяются изменения того потока, кто первый сделал комит. Опоздавшему вылетает exception (о том, что ресурс был изменен другим)

*слева поток1 просто закрылся, т.к. фоновый*

[image: слева поток1 просто закрылся, т.к. фоновый]

Comment: Такое же поведение будет и для `SNAPSHOT ISOLATION`, который более предсказуем в плане блокировок.

Answer (score 1):

В EF эта проблема решается добавлением Concurrency Token - времени последнего изменения строки. Тогда код сохранения для каждого из пользователей будет проверять, не поменялась ли строка с момента загрузки:

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // поле для отслеживания даты изменения
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

или, вместо аттрибута `[Timestamp]`, при fluent-конфигурации:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
    .Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsConcurrencyToken();
```

EF будет добавит проверку на то, что RowVersion не поменялся, во все генерируемые `Update` и `Delete` вида:

```
UPDATE ... SET A = 2 WHERE Id = @id AND @rowVersion = version1
```

Второе возможное решение - расставить на "опасные" свойства аттрибут [`[ConcurrencyCheck]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.concurrencycheckattribute.concurrencycheckattribute.aspx). Тогда при Update/Delete будут проверены значения отмеченных свойств. Т.е. в вашем случае апрейд будет выглядеть как:

```
UPDATE ... SET A = 2 WHERE ID = @id AND A = 1
```

У первого пользователя обновление пройдет успешно. У второго - SQL обновит 0 строк, EF обнаружит это и бросит `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` или `OptimisticConcurrencyException`, который вам придется обработать (например, повторением действия для второго пользовател заново).

Сам механизм и подробности обработки очень подробно расписаны в стандартном туториале [Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework 6](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: А как у EF с pessimistic (то есть по сути привычной) concurrency? В статье написаны лишь общие слова.

Comment: Нужно решение на уровне транзакций или контекста

Comment: @VladD никак. pessimistic - это худший вариант concurrency, который вообще очень применим. Потому что он практически превращает приложение в однопользовательское (в худшем случае). поэтому он если и "привычный", то только для winforms/wpf. в веб pessimistic вообще нельзя нормально реализовать - из-за того, что пользователь может просто взять и не продолжить работу, что вызывает проблему подвисших блокировок.

Comment: @GLeBaTi На уровне просто транзакций это реализовать нельзя - ни один из стандартныйх уровней изоляции не запрещает одновременное чтение. На чистом SQL это реализуется обычными `SELECT WITH UPDLOCK` или `HOLDLOCK`. Ну и соответствующими костылями, если вы используете EF.

Comment: @GLeBaTi есть еще очень некрасивый вариант с принудительным фейковым апдейтом строки (или дополнительной таблицы) перед ее селектом, чтобы поставить лок. Или с созданием спецтаблицы для локов и вызовом вида `SELECT NULL FROM TestTable WITH (UPDLOCK)` перед чтением данных. Но это по сути костыль, и никак не тянет на best practices.

Comment: @PashaPash а если мне использовать IsolationLevel=Serializable - это решит мою проблему? Какие подводные камни?

Comment: @GLeBaTi Не решит. Serializable вообще делает не то, что подразумевается из его названия. Он не "выстраивает транзакции одну за одной". И никак не помешает другой транзакции выбрать старые данные. Можете попробовать - выполните `set transaction isolation level Serializable begin tran select top 1 * from sometable` в одном окне management studio, и точно такую же строчку в другом - обе строчки отработают, обе транзакции вычитают данные.

Comment: @PashaPash: Жалко. На самом деле в некоторых сценариях такое нужно. Например: если машина находится в пути, то список грузов должно быть нельзя отредактировать. Это выглядело бы куда профессиональнее, чем возможность отредактировать и сообщение об ошибке в момент записи.